# rpmbuild, then install the rpm, then upgrade from repositories

Tags: yum, compiling, upgrade, rpmbuild

I am a very novice administrator. Building my own production environment is my target. Which will be similar to professional ones.

I wonder if it is better to install critical applications from the source or through the package manager. 
My idea is:
- compilation from the source with rpmbuild, then install the rpm package, then upgrade from repositories (via yum).

I wonder if my configuration will be taken into account when upgrading the package by yum.

./configure --enable-ssl --enable-so --enable-http2 --with-mpm = event --with-included-apr --with-ssl = / usr / local / openssl --prefix = / usr / local / apache2

Comment: Is the package you're trying to install from source either: 1.) a newer version than the version in the repository, or 2.) Not in the repository?

Comment: If you have no real reason to, I would avoid rebuilding yourself from source. `yum install` is way faster and easier.

Comment: 1) I know it is easier, but I think that thanks to the compilation, I can adapt the software better. What's your opinion ?

2) No, the software is not newer than the one contained in the official repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no real reason to, I would avoid rebuilding yourself from source. `yum install` is way faster and easier.

Second: if you run something like

```
./configure
make
make install
```

then those files will not be taken into account by the `rpm` database; so `rpm` (and hence `yum`) won't know that those files exist.

Comment: to my knowledge, if I build my own .rpm (with rpmbuild), then install it, it will be in the database. Am I wrong?

  I just wonder if the settings from ./configure will not be changed to default ones after the upgrade.

For the record, I am writing about critical applications.

Comment: if you build your own rpm, then the files will be in the database, yes.

Comment: What happens to my settings after the upgrade?

Comment: I don't understand that question. an `rpm` packages **files**, not **settings**...

Comment: according to this guide in the section% build
CFLAGS = "$ RPM_OPT_FLAGS" ./configure --prefix =% {_ prefix} --mandir =% {_ mandir} --sysconfdir = / etc


I can include my own options.

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/02/rpm-build-package-example/